# Visual composer plugin seems to not working on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I have a online web site with Visual Composer plugin, and all works fine.

Today I downloaded this site in local, but Seems That the VC plugin does not work because the page layout is wrong and some parts of the pages are no longer visible.

I think that these parts are used by VC.

Does anyone know what happened?

Thanks

-- UPLOAD --

I think I found the problem. Custom css files (of theme) are not loaded on pages.

For example on remote site pages load css/custom-f5s6da4f.css file, instead in local not.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Now I saw that the problem could be the "the7" theme. On server website the page use a custom css, like this (/dt-the7/css/custom-f54dfs6ad4.css). In local version doesn't happen. Any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded website from server to local you will need to update wordpress & website URL. Currently website is not able to load various assets CSS/JS check browser console. If you see short-codes for visual composer then its issue with Visual Composer plugin.

Comment: hi, thanks. I changed all URL from db backup (from server url to local). And in wp admin I changed permalink from "post-name" to "default". But it does not work anyway.

Comment: In case it solves the problem kindly mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if someone could help.

The custom css were blocked. The first error may be that the folders do not have the permission.

The second (what is served to me) is to reset and restore the custom CSS: theme option / general / advanced (tab) -> 'disabled' and than 'enabled' responsive layout.

have a nice day